# Argument matching parameter narrows to 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: .net, vb.net, callback, addressof

During a refactor of some code, I've started getting this error.  As far as I can tell I haven't changed anything that would affect this, nor have I changed the method signature.

Here is the method:

```
Public Sub DisplayMessage(msg as String, callBack As System.EventHandler) Implements IMyInterface.DisplayMessage

    ...

End Sub
```

And here's how it's called:

```
MessageInstance.DisplayMessage("test", _
    AddressOf MyFunc)
```

And MyFunc is just:

```
Private Sub MyFunc()
   ...
End Sub
```

I currently have two versions of the code, the refactored one is giving the compile error:

```
Argument matching parameter 'callBack' narrows to 'System.EventHandler'
```

And the previous version is not.

The only change that has been made to this is that the the DisplayMessage function, and the MessageInstance class has move into a separate library.  Can anyone provide an explanation as to why this error is occurring or, preferably, why it is NOW occurring?

Comment: You didn't turn Option Strict On did you?

Comment: No, I just checked, and it's default (which I believe is off) everywhere.  I tried explicitly setting it to Off (even though as a C# dev that makes me feel dirty), but to no avail.

Comment: It shouldn't compile, MyFunc's signature doesn't match the delegate.  Just fix the code, `Sub MyFunc(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)`.